# How to enable nanoseconds in boost::posix_time?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use `nanoseconds` type define in `boost::posix_time` but it appears that this type is not defined. I looked in the implementation and it looks like the type definition is protected by

```
#if defined(BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_NANOSECONDS)
```

so I added to my code

```
# define BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_NANOSECONDS
```

but I keep getting the same compilation error. I in some pages on the web I saw that I might need to rebuild my boost library which is perfectly fine with me but I didn't see any related flags in `bootstrap.sh` or `b2` and even if that was the problem I would expect this problem to appear during linkage not compilation. Any ideas what is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I would expect this problem to appear during linkage not compilation` Why's that? Macros are expanded during [pre-]compilation, not linking.

Comment: I meant that if the issue was that I didn't built the boost library correctly then the problem would have appeared during linkage rather than [pre-]compilation

Comment: Oh right, got you; yes, I suppose so. Depends on whether the option leads to different symbols being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html):

> #### Introduction
>
> Defines a non-adjusted time system with nano-second/micro-second resolution and stable calculation properties. The nano-second resolution option uses 96 bits of underlying storage for each ptime while the micro-second resolution uses 64 bits per ptime (see [Build Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#date_time.buildinfo) for details). This time system uses the Gregorian calendar to implement the date portion of the time representation.

And the build options page says:

> To use the alternate resolution (96 bit nanosecond) the variable `BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG` must be defined in the library users project files (ie Makefile, Jamfile, etc).

### Please read the documentation.

Comment: I literally Googled this in about 45 seconds.

Comment: OK, you were right, I had to add this parameter to the Makefile, not to the source code

Comment: @e271p314: In general, don't just define random macros.